# how to pass useState set state function to a child component in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I recently started using typescript and I'm having trouble with passing a use state setter function,

my parent component is is this :

```
const [word, setword] = useState('run')
```

and in the child im passing :

```
<Child word={word} setword={setword}/>
```

the child has this :

```
    interface Props {
      word: string
      
      setword: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
    }
    const VoicetoText: React.FC<Props> = (word, setword) => {
    return (
{word}
<button onClick={()=>setword('hey buddy')} ><button/>
    )}
```

i keep getting an error :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a curly brace to

```
const VoicetoText: React.FC<Props> = (word, setword)
```

either use props or deconstruct the
props

```
const VoicetoText: React.FC<Props> = (props) 
props.setWord
```

deconstruct

```
const VoicetoText: React.FC<Props> = ({word, setword})
```

Comment: Please avoid using React.FC, it brings a little benefit compared to how many props it compromises. You can just type it like regular function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setword: (word: string) => void` as the prop type.

```
interface Props {
  word: string      
  setword: (word: string) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not make your life harder and go wtih something like:

```
const Child = ({setWord}: {setWord: (arg0: string}) => void) => {
  // () => setWord("word") is jsut for sample sake, you should avoid using arrow function calls inside event handleres like this
  return <button onClick={() => setWord("word")}>Click me</button>
}

const Parent = () => {

  const [word, setWord] = useState(false);

  return <Child propName={setWord}/>
}
```